# AppInitializer always launches android for cross platform tests

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.uitest

I'm writing a UI Test that is supposed to be cross platform between Android and IOS.

When I run my App Initializer on a Mac, the "platform" Xamarin object always resolves as android (confirmed when running the tests in debug mode) even though I have an iOS simulator open and an iOS device plugged in with no Andorid simulators or devices connected.

```
public static IApp StartApp(Platform platform)
    {
        if (platform == Platform.Android)
        {
            return ConfigureApp
                .Android
                .ApkFile("../../Binaries/Android/com.xamarin.samples.taskyandroid.apk")
                .StartApp();
        }

        return ConfigureApp
            .iOS
            .AppBundle("../../Binaries/iOS/TaskyiOS.app")
            .DeviceIdentifier("Device id")
            .StartApp();
    }
```

The only time I can launch an iOS simulator is when I comment out the if condition without evaluating platform.

How can I get the appinitializer to detect iOS as the platform?

Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: I'm having this same issue, did you manage to solve this?

Comment: For the sake of future Users, if the answer below solves your issue, please mark it as the solution. Thanks.

Comment: @JamesMundy Did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you are running your tests for the desired OS, from the `Unit Tests` (XS) or `Test Explorer` (VS) window

- `Xamarin Studio` >> `View` >> `Pads` >> `Unit Tests`
- `Visual Studio` >> `Tests` >> `Test Explorer`

I beleive `platform` will default to Android if you use the `Play / Run` button, while the UITest project is selected as the `Startup Project`, or if you use `Run All` (starting with Android since it appears before iOS)

*(wow, that image is huge, sorry)*
[image]