# Xamarin.UITest Platform enum always returning Android

Tags: xamarin, bdd, xcode-ui-testing, calabash, xamarin.uitest

I have referred [AppInitializer always launches android for cross platform tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37731970/appinitializer-always-launches-android-for-cross-platform-tests/40269238#40269238) post

still none of the solutions are helping me out, whenever I run BDD tests by default Platform is getting value as Android.
How can I make it dynamically pick the platform values?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a BaseTest class that inherited by all test class with decorated with PlatformTestFixture attribute. Then we can start Android or iOS app based on platform parameter that passed in.

```
public class PlatformTestFixtureAttribute : TestFixtureAttribute
{
    public PlatformTestFixtureAttribute()
    {
    }

    public PlatformTestFixtureAttribute(params object[] arguments)
        : base(arguments)
    {
        AddPlatformCategory(arguments);
    }

    private void AddPlatformCategory(object[] args)
    {
        // Not needed in TestCloud
        if (!TestEnvironment.IsTestCloud)
        {
            foreach (var arg in args)
            {
                if (arg is Platform)
                {
                    if (Platform.Android == (Platform)arg)
                    {
                        AddAndroidCategory();
                    }
                    else if (Platform.iOS == (Platform)arg)
                    {
                        AddiOSCategory();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void AddAndroidCategory()
    {
        Category = "AndroidTest";
    }

    private void AddiOSCategory()
    {
        Category = "iOSTest";
    }
}

[PlatformTestFixture(Platform.Android)]
[PlatformTestFixture(Platform.iOS)]
public abstract class BaseTest
{
    Platform _platform;
    protected BaseTest(Platform platform)
    {
        _platform = platform;
    }

    [SetUp]
    public virtual void BeforeEachTest()
    {
        if (platform == Platform.Android)
        {
            StartAndroidApp();
        }
        else
        {
            StartiOSApp();
        }
    }
}

public class ChildTest : BaseTest
{
    public ChildTest(Platform platform)
        : base(platform)
    {
    }

    [Test]
    public void SomeTest()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then I can run the test in command line specifying whether to run iOSTest or AndroidTest.

```
[NUnit] [Test Fixture DLL Path] -include=AndroidTest
OR
[NUnit] [Test Fixture DLL Path] -include=iOSTest
```